# How to know if EOF when running a C program with redirected input?

Tags: c, file-io, io

I am running a C program with redirected input from a text file like so:

```
./a.out < data.txt
```

data.txt is a bunch of words, one on each line, like so:

```
WORDONE
WORDTWO
WORDTHREE
WORDFOUR
```

My program is getting the input one word at a time. Is there a way to detect when I have reached the last word? Is there a way to check for EOF when using redirected input?

Here is my code for reading the input:

```
int main() {
    char word[51];
    while(getNextWord(word)) {
        printf("%s\n", word);
    }
}

int getNextWord(char word[51]) {
    char input[51];
    scanf("%s", input);
    if (strcmp(input, word) != 0) {
        strcpy(word, input);
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: I would be really surprised if it worked any differently than ordinary file input.

Comment: Yes but with ordinary file input you have a file pointer, so I didn't know if there was a different way to detect EOF.

Comment: It appears that the [getline POSIX function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) returns a -1 when EOF is encountered.

Comment: Check the return value of scanf. You should always check the return value of scanf. It will tell you if it managed to read or not.

Comment: It appears that the standard [fgets function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html) returns a null pointer when EOF is encountered.  I suggest you use one of those two functions rather than scanf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a check to make sure that `scanf` was successful.

Instead of just:

```
scanf("%s", input);
```

use:

```
// Specify a maximum width to prevent buffer overflow
if ( scanf("%50s", input) == 1 )
{
   // Success. Use input.
   return 1;
}
else
{
   // Most likely EOF has been reached.
   // Do the right thing.
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: scanf return number of input items successfully matched and assigned,  so"if( scanf("%50s", input) == 1 )"  will be wrong. we can check the return value of scanf is EOF to find end of input i think.

Comment: @NaveenKumar, there is only item to assign to. If that is successful, `scanf` would return `1`. If there were two items to assign to, then you would check the return value of `scanf` against `2`.

Comment: @R Sahu. yeha got it.I got confused between read and scanf. :)